# Simple uppercase encryption algorithm

Tags: php, security, encryption

I am using a system to sell tickets for a game.

Current id numbers for tickets are consecutive. EG: 651,652,653. If someone would buy a new ticket, his ticket id would be 654.

I am looking for a solution to inform the user about his ticket unique id by sending him a string instead of the ticket number, so that he can have a reference, but he would not know how many tickets were purchased before.

By encrypting ticket number 651 I want to generate a string having 6-7 characters maximum, all uppercase, and this algorithm should be two way and reversed only using a secret key.
EG: using a key like 881hu and encrypting number 651 I should obtain something like UTR8N1A0 .

I want uppercase letters for readability, and the length of the new string should not be too long, because then it would be hard to remember.

Do I have any options of such algorithm? I am using PHP as server language for all this.

Comment: Assuming your using a database for storing sales, why not generate a unique RANDOM reference to the record for REFERENCING from the database? I don't see why a 2 way x char encryption would be required?

Comment: Why not just add a number before it? ticket 654 becomes 250654, 655 becomes 250655 etc... Your proposed solution seems abit overkill.

Comment: Database would be ideal. The runner-up would be using any secure encryption method such as AES with a secret key (this will produce something that looks like gibberish but can be decoded).

Note that it doesn't actually matter what encryption mode you use since your entire ticket number should easily fit into a single block so you can't really use cryptanalysis to determine your ticket number. I would actually advocate using ECB-mode so you don't have to track an IV as long as you promise to never use ECB again after this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @RaggaMuffin-420 comment, that way you can have 6-7 uppercase characters maximum. As for something like **mcrypt** there's no easy way to make it in 6-7 chars... 
of course if you don't want to do something silly like:

```
$secret = 123456789;
$tickedID = 654;

$code = strtoupper( dechex($secret + $tickedID) );

echo 'Code is: ' . $code . '<br>';

$decode = hexdec($code) - $secret;
echo 'Decoded: ' . $decode;
```

**Output:**

```
Code is: 75BCFA3
Decoded: 654
```

**Disclaimer:** I would go with adding unique code in database referencing to the actual ticked id.

Comment: Once you make all letters uppercase how do you know which ones were lower case if you wanna reverse the algorithm?

Comment: There is no difference between uppercase and lowercase letters in hexadecimal interpretation. Just your secret must be a number, can't be a string.

Comment: Please note that you can use this just as a very basic encryption, breaking this can be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

One option - you can calculate a hash(consecutive_number + salt) and then encode the hash.

Update: If you need to quickly extract the original consecutive_number, hide it inside the encoded hash string. You can read it, and you can verify it by re-calculating the hash (as the salt is secret, one won't be able to easily calculate the hash to construct a valid key).

Comment: He wants a two-way algorithm.

Comment: @akirilov, I'm also not sure he *needs* two-way. I think OP wants a way to *verify*. In that case a hash is adequate. Maybe a keyed hash would be more secure though, with a simple hash the user could easily bruteforce his number.

Comment: Ah, another commented mentioned 2-way, not the OP. I agree with hash+salt then if he doesn't need to reverse it (I figured he might for verification).

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of bad advice floating around the Internet (and bad designs like "hashids"), but ultimately what you want is:

#### Don't do this:

[image: Encryption]

### Do this instead:

[image: Use a random lookup]

Images (and detailed arguments) from: [The Comprehensive Guide to URL Parameter Encryption in PHP](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php)